# Organize pictures in html

Tags: html

I need to add a white row below the each line of 4 pictures or somehting to organice my pictures in a better way. I'm new in HTML lenguage. Maybe I can set the pictures in a grid but I don't know how.,

Now, my html is this:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<!-- start portfolio Section -->
<section id="protfolio_sec">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs12 ">
                <div class="title_sec">
                    <h1>Our Portfolio</h1>
                    <h2>WE’RE BRANDING & DIGITAL STUDIO FROM VIET NAM</h2>
                </div>          
            </div>
        </div>       
    <div class="all-portfolios">
        <div class="col-sm-6  col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 ">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1Tyw2_WSc0vtAOEkGGNMoKUOalqkpTGhU" alt="">     
        </div>        
        <div class="col-sm-6  col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 ">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1_m349B3UpIEe_H6GTS_iIOSau5_ui495" alt="">     
        </div>          
        <div class="col-sm-6  col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 ">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=16NHSj04XvEOGF0FMvpGOZZzTenSLjbYs" alt="">      
        </div>          
        <div class="col-sm-6  col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 ">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1T7e1E7Nkr37zVsPMorwZ1epSBzQDNxCi" alt="">       
        </div>          
        <div class="col-sm-6  col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 ">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1StRD1M5VIgsjppFfLHoo5jm4nFCYaXc8" alt="">      
        </div>          
        <div class="col-sm-6  col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 ">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1sEOoK3DkPL1Ae3Ssbbl_UUicweSXey-0" alt="">      
        </div>        
        <div class="col-sm-6  col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 ">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1h2jHdeHdKonUV4b-chwDbFTDFL3kgjbg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6  col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 ">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1tHObIoEXvU7Q-VqKco-r0TbDNbi9UK2L" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6  col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 ">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1UGow9lO1acWYK3sg4laTNrZ7ksIuaahk" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6  col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 ">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1ICItudvz6ekE4MMTio6D-il2jxiIjYzg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6  col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 ">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1bnfzSAKZpdBoC1JgCBI5oMKrG39DVA1X" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6  col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 ">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1GXSPr1z0-L2bHyb4-9XJ1Bt5Mg_jeKDr" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post_btn">
    </div>      
    </div>
</section>
<!-- End Portfolio Section -->
```

Comment: You want to do what?

Comment: Sepárate the lines of pictures @Amy

Comment: I solved with this: <br></br>@Amy

Comment: @MartinBouhier I added an answer for you. You shouldn't be using br to do that. :)

Comment: [The `br` HTML element doesn't have a closing tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br), and using it here is not an appropriate usage.  You're better off with a table or some CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `<br>` to accomplish what you want, as the `br` element won't be responsive, whereas all your other code will be.

You may want to add some margin in your CSS to create a gap between images:

```
.all-portfolios img{
  margin: .5em;
}
```

Note: `<br>` doesn't have a closing tag.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the table in HTML . This has rows (tr) and columns (td)
See the example below. Control the width of the table and padding , and cellspacing as required. Also read more about the table tag online :

```
    <table width="800" cellspacing="20" cellpadding="20">
        <tr>
            <td width="33%" valign="top">
               <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1Tyw2_WSc0vtAOEkGGNMoKUOalqkpTGhU" alt="">     

            </td>
            <td width="33%" valign="top">
               <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1Tyw2_WSc0vtAOEkGGNMoKUOalqkpTGhU" alt="">     

            </td>
            <td width="33%" valign="top">
               <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1Tyw2_WSc0vtAOEkGGNMoKUOalqkpTGhU" alt="">     

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="33%" valign="top">
               <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1Tyw2_WSc0vtAOEkGGNMoKUOalqkpTGhU" alt="">     

            </td>
            <td width="33%" valign="top">
               <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1Tyw2_WSc0vtAOEkGGNMoKUOalqkpTGhU" alt="">     

            </td>
            <td width="33%" valign="top">
               <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1Tyw2_WSc0vtAOEkGGNMoKUOalqkpTGhU" alt="">     

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```